# How to select from Drupal with alias

Tags: drupal, drupal-database

I want to get 1 column from a table in Drupal as 2 aliases. Something like this but with Drupal's query methods.:

```
SELECT name AS label, name AS value FROM node WHERE 1
```

This Drupal code doesn't set the right alias:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'node');
$query->fields('node', array('label' => 'name','value' => 'name'));
```

It returns something like: `[name] => Science [node_name] => Science`

Is there any way to set the alias?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The 'fields' method does not allow you to set aliases. If you look at the docs, the second argument for fields is an indexed array, so numbers only.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery::fields/7

If you need aliases, then you need to use 'addField'.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--select.inc/function/SelectQuery::addField/7

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');

$query->addField('n', 'name', 'label');
$query->addField('n', 'name', 'value');
```

Comment: thanks. i tried searching the documentation, but either the doc is badly structured, or google doesn't index it.